# Why would my Windows 7 inside VirtualBox not see other computers on network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox

I installed Windows 7 inside **VirtualBox** on Windows 7.

- **Host Windows 7** can see virtual Windows 7.
- **Other computers** on the network can see Host Windows 7 and virtual Windows 7.
- But **virtual Windows 7** cannot see any other computers on the network, and when I explicitly type in the address of another computer e.g. "\desktop-pc", it says it cannot find it.

**What do I have to do so that the virtual windows 7 sees other computers including its host on the network?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to change your network settings inside the virtual machine.

Go into the settings, click on the network tab, then change it to a bridged connection. Select the network adapter you use to connect to your network, then restart the virtual machine. It will now get an IP address from your router and act as a separate computer on your network.

[image]